# Dropdown has no content (bootstrap framework)

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I have the following code for a dropdown using the `bootstrap-sass` gem:

```
<div class="nav-collapse collapse" style="height:0px;">
            <nav>
              <ul class= "nav pull-right">
                <% if signed_in? %>
                    <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
                  <li><%= link_to "Users", users_path %></li>
                  <li id = "fat-menu" class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                      Account <b class="caret"></b>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><%= link_to "Settings", edit_user_path(current_user) %></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li>
                        <%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, method: "delete" %>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <% else %>
                    <li><%= link_to "Sign In", signin_path %></li>
                <%end%>
              </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
```

However when I click on `Account` it shows the following only and not the contents:

[image]

You can see the little white triangle that shows it's been clicked on but no contents. When I'm debugging I can also see the menu in chrome here:
[image]

Comment: Have you also included the bootstrap js file? Not sure if it's necessary for this but worth a look.

Comment: Yeah it's included. I think that's why the little white triangle shows up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Don't need the class `collapse` in first div.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
  Account <b class="caret"></b>
</a>
```

You should use:

```
<a href="#fat-menu" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
  Account <b class="caret"></b>
</a>
```

Also, please provide the JavaScript file that enables this menu (it isn't just including the JS files, you must enable the dropdown somewhere). It would look like this:

```
$(".dropdown-toggle").dropdown();
```

Comment: i'm using the bootstrap-sass gem, isn't it done in there by default?

Answer (score 0):

If you do want collapse in the first div, use:

```
.collapse .dropdown{
  overflow: visible !important;
}
```